# Disable notifications of a Chrome Extension that you don't control

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm using a Chrome Extension, which I like a lot, but it shows notifications, which I find distracting. I want to disable those notifications. I'm using Linux Mint, and the notifications are shown in the panel (at the bottom of the screen).

I've checked `chrome.management` API, but haven't found anything related to disabling notifications. Also googling didn't provide any results.

The only way I can think of is installing the same
extension via `Developer mode`, creating a system script that would be watching the original Chrome Extension folder for changes, and on every change, copy the content to the Developer Mode folder (modified), modify it after each update to remove the `notifications` permission, and then reload the Developer Mode extension inside Chrome via a shortcut, for example.

I'm wondering if there is any simpler way to accomplish this.